# Serving interactive bokeh figure on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, bokeh

I'm trying to serve an interactive `bokeh` figure via heroku. The figure I'm trying to have served is essentially equivalent to this one ([example](https://demo.bokehplots.com/apps/movies), [code](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/movies/main.py)).  I'm new to both `bokeh` and `heroku` so I'm pretty sure I'm missing something pretty basic -- I think what I'm trying to do should be quite straightforward.

First, I can serve my figure locally using the `bokeh serve --show myapp` command. Where `myapp` is the name of the python module that includes the `bokeh` figure.  Note that the `--show` flag just prompts `bokeh` to open a browser window once the figure is built and the server is running.

Next, I've setup a `heroku` account, and created my first app, following the steps in the [*Heroku - Getting Started With Python* tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction). My git repository includes `myapp`, a `requirements.txt` file, and `Procfile`.

Alas, something is not working and I'm stumped. I have tried a bunch of different options in my `Procfile` and none have worked.  Since the `bokeh serve ...` command starts a server, shouldn't a `Procfile` that looks like this do the trick:

```
web: bokeh serve --port $PORT myapp
```

Should that work? Perhaps I'm missing something and I need to create a `flask` app that wraps around my `bokeh` app but as far as I can tell, that doesn't seem necessary. Maybe someone knows of a nice tutorial that pulls all of these steps together, I haven't found a complete one yet.

**Update:**
I'm pasting a bit of my `heroku` logs below. How do you handle this `--host whitelist` issue?

```
2016-07-17T05:00:46.513139+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-07-17T05:00:46.366909+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 9b63d8a by me@me.com
2016-07-17T05:00:46.367087+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by me@me.com
2016-07-17T05:00:46.624937+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-07-17T05:00:55.188978+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bokeh serve --port=39665 myapp.py`
2016-07-17T05:00:57.876287+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-07-17 05:00:57,876 Starting Bokeh server on port 39665 with applications at paths ['/myapp']
2016-07-17T05:00:57.868758+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-07-17 05:00:57,868 Starting Bokeh server version 0.12.0
2016-07-17T05:00:57.876378+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-07-17 05:00:57,876 Starting Bokeh server with process id: 3
2016-07-17T05:00:58.800309+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-07-17T05:00:59.970326+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-07-17 05:00:59,970 Rejected connection from host 'myapp.herokuapp.com' because it is not in the --host whitelist
2016-07-17T05:00:59.973495+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-07-17 05:00:59,970 403 GET / (XX.XX.XXX.XX) 1.29ms
2016-07-17T05:00:59.975282+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx fwd="XX.XX.XX.XX" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=403 bytes=219
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm just going to answer my own question since I was eventually able to get this to work and nobody else has answered it yet.

I ended up with a `Procfile` that looked like this:

```
web: bokeh serve --port=$PORT --host=myapp.herokuapp.com --host=* \
     --address=0.0.0.0 --use-xheaders myapp.py
```

a bit of background on what all of these arguments mean (as far as I can tell):

`--port`: specifies the port that the `bokeh` server will listen on, `$PORT` is set by `heroku`

`--host=myapp.herokuapp.com` and `--host=*`: specify the host name as `myapp.heroku...`, the wildcard is supposed to allow all hosts to be accepted. I'm not sure this in needed anymore.

`--address=0.0.0.0`: I think this tells `bokeh` to figure out on its own, which IP address it will be on.

`--use-xheaders`: causes `bokeh` to override the remote IP and URI scheme/protocol

I'm happy to make edits to this or accept a more knowledgeable users answer if there are issues with this approach.

Comment: Were you able to deploy it with flask? I have a working flask app locally, but cannot figure out how to make it work on Heroku. Here is the [bokeh_plot.py](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ohaa388wpmkvpxt/bokeh_plot.py?dl=0) and [app.py](https://www.dropbox.com/s/owla19e58hgijgd/app.py?dl=0) containing the flask code.
Script app.py contains a subprocess where the bokeh server is started so the application can start by simply running `python app.py` and the app is succesfully rendered in localhost:5000. Now, I don't know how to modify bokeh_subprocess to make it work on Heroku.

Comment: I never got a flask app running with my setup.  I just used the `bokeh serve` command and was able to skip the `flask` step.

Comment: I see, but you need a web framework if you need to add other content along your bokeh chart, right?

Comment: --address of 0.0.0.0 means "listen on all network interfaces" ; it may be the default anyway?

Comment: --host=* is a security problem and should not be needed. This tells bokeh to trust any client-provided Host header, and put that host in front of URLs it generates.

Comment: --use-xheaders is needed and tells bokeh to trust "x headers" set by the Heroku reverse proxy. These are headers Heroku adds to pass on info about the client.

Comment: to make flask+bokeh work on Heroku I think you need two different web workers because you need to listen on two different ports.

Comment: @HavocP I tried to add another web worker in Procfile by making it look like this: `web: gunicorn app:app web: bokeh serve --port=$PORT --host=bokehapp.herokuapp.com --host=* --address=0.0.0.0 --use-xheaders bokeh_plot.py`. That showed the graph at bokeh.herokuapp.com/bokeh_plot, but it didn't show the content served by Flask. It seems the server is reading the second line only. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: each Heroku app can only have one web worker iirc. so you would need two different Heroku apps, or some kind of intermediate process that listens on the one port and routes to bokeh or flask as needed.

Comment: @jhamman if you don't mind, could you share a sample requirements.txt and Proctofile for a basic bokeh&heroku app ?

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer didn't work for me as written (likely due to a bokeh version difference), but since this is still one of the top hits for this question, here is my minor modification that did work:

```
web: bokeh serve --port=$PORT --num-procs=0 --allow-websocket-origin=myapp.herokuapp.com --address=0.0.0.0 --use-xheaders myapp.py
```