# requirement.txt to run bokeh application on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, bokeh

I want to run a bokeh app on heroku. As an example, I can give the following code I took from this [website](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#connecting-with-bokeh-client).

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi

from bokeh.client import push_session
from bokeh.driving import cosine
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc

x = np.linspace(0, 4*pi, 80)
y = np.sin(x)

p = figure()
r1 = p.line([0, 4*pi], [-1, 1], color="firebrick")
r2 = p.line(x, y, color="navy", line_width=4)

# open a session to keep our local document in sync with server
session = push_session(curdoc())

@cosine(w=0.03)
def update(step):
    # updating a single column of the the *same length* is OK
    r2.data_source.data["y"] = y * step
    r2.glyph.line_alpha = 1 - 0.8 * abs(step)

curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 50)

session.show(p) # open the document in a browser

session.loop_until_closed() # run forever
```

So, to run this on heroku, I've found that, I need to do the steps explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417200/serving-interactive-bokeh-figure-on-heroku).

However, it is not stated here or somewhere else what should I add to the requirements.txt file when I use bokeh. Is there anyone who can help me about this and other things that I need to do for running a bokeh app on heroku?

Comment: The easiest way to create a `requirements.txt` file, assuming you already have the code running locally with everything installed, is `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. Note that if you don't use a per-project virtualenv this will probably contain a bunch of stuff you actually don't need.

Comment: Alternatively if you are using `conda` you can run `conda list --export` but the very short list of requirements is also given below.

Answer (score 0):

The list of runtime requirements for Bokeh is veryy short. They are given in the project [setup.py](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/setup.py):

```
REQUIRES = [
    'six >=1.5.2',
    'requests >=1.2.3',
    'PyYAML >=3.10',
    'python-dateutil >=2.1',
    'Jinja2 >=2.7',
    'numpy >=1.7.1',
    'tornado >=4.3',
]

# handle the compat difference for futures 
if sys.version_info[:2] == (2, 7):
    REQUIRES.append('futures >=3.0.3')
```

There are some optional dependencies. `bokeh.charts` depends on Pandas, and using custom extensions depends on having NodeJS installed (via `conda` or some other means)