# Deploying server-based bokeh app using heroku

Tags: python, git, heroku, bokeh

I'm trying to do the same thing as in [Serving interactive bokeh figure on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417200/serving-interactive-bokeh-figure-on-heroku/38447618#38447618).  But even after reading the answer, I can't figure it out.

I've cloned the bokeh git repository and downloaded the data.  Then, by executing the command

```
bokeh serve --show movies
```

(the python file is located in the movies subdirectory) in git bash, I can view the app locally on port 5006.

But what I really want is to deploy the app to the internet.  I'm trying to use heroku to do this.  This is a non-flask, non-django app.

For the procfile, I have

```
web: bokeh serve --port=$PORT --host=movies-rohan.herokuapp.com --host=* --address=0.0.0.0 --use-xheaders movies.py
```

Two questions about this:

1) Should I specify the port number, or leave it as $PORT?

2) Should I use "--allow-websocket-origin=" instead of "--host"?  Does it make a difference?

Then there's the requirements.txt file.  As I understand, this lists the dependencies for the app.  But I don't know how to format this.  Can anyone, please, provide a template for a requirements.txt file?  As a sample requirements.txt, does this seem reasonable:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[packages]
bokeh = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

Besides the python file, the procfile, and requirements.txt, is anything else necessary?  What about a pipfile, pipfile.lock, or procfile.windows?  My understanding is that a pipfile is an alternative to requirements.txt.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to define the port number.

I think your Procfile should contain this command : 
`web: bokeh serve --port=$PORT --allow-websocket-origin=movies-rohan.herokuapp.com --address=0.0.0.0 --use-xheaders movies`

I am assuming your movies.py file is in **movies folder**

Comment: I think the `movies.py` file should be placed in the folder `movies` and renamed to `main.py`.